# classic asp connection

Tags: html, sql, vbscript, asp-classic

How would you go about getting user input for a connection over different webpages. Would this be done with session variables or is there another way. I dont want to have to set up connections on every webpage, can someone point me in the right direction what to do some research into.

Here is a bit of code from a site that does not have any connection strings at all on the web site.

```
obj_ADO.ClearParameters
lng_RecSet1 = obj_ADO.GetFreeRecordset
obj_ADO.Recordset "A_combo_Permissions_select", adCmdStoredProc, obj_Session.int_CommandTimeout, lng_RecSet1
while obj_ADO.EOF(lng_RecSet1) = 0
```

and

if str_Action = obj_Session.str_FileName or len(str_Action)=0 or str_Action = str_SwitchLangText then

```
obj_ADO.ClearParameters
obj_ADO.AddParameter "SessionID", adChar, adParamInput, len(obj_Session.str_SessionID), obj_Session.str_SessionID
obj_ADO.AddParameter "PermissionID", adInteger, adParamInput, 8, lng_PermissionID
lng_RecSet = obj_ADO.GetFreeRecordset
obj_ADO.Recordset "A_PagePermissions_select", adCmdStoredProc, obj_Session.int_CommandTimeout, lng_RecSet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Database** connection

it's normal to adopt a custom library that at least as the methods to `open connection`, `execute query` and `close connection`

Example:

```
<%
    '' Database file database.asp

    Sub openDB(query, objConn, objRS)

        Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        objConn.ConnectionString = "DSN=myCONNECTION.dsn"
        objConn.Open

        Set objRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        objRS.Open query, objConn

    End Sub

    Sub CloseRs(objRS)

        objRS.Close
        Set objRS = Nothing

    End Sub

    Sub CloseDb(objConn)

        objConn.Close
        Set objConn = Nothing

    End Sub

%>
```

then you can simple use:

```
<!--#include file="header.inc"-->
<%
    Dim rs, conn
    openDb("SELECT Name FROM TBL_USERS", conn, rs)

    '' you can loop through the rs object now
    while NOT rs.EOF

        Response.Write rs("Name")

        rs.MoveNext
    wend

    closeRs(rs)
    closeDb(conn)
%>
```

---

(old post message as I did not saw the `sql` tag

In **Classic ASP** it always ends up using

`Request.QueryString("myInput")` or `Request.Forms("myInput")` or yet a 2-in-1 `Request("myInput")` and work from there

"Connections" are made by links and form Post's / Get's

There are plenty of examples on the web, but [here's one](http://www.tizag.com/aspTutorial/aspFormsPost.php)

**To keep variables across pages** you have (as still today) 3 ways

- `Session` variable, it leaves per user session
- `Application` variable, it leaves per website and it's shared cross all users
- `Cookies`

for example, the "Authorized Page access" is made by setting a `Session` upon the correct login, forward using `Response.Redirect("myProtectedPage.asp")` and in that page normally looks like:

```
<%
    If Session("user-login") = True Then
        Response.Redirect("NotAuthorized.asp")
    End if
%>
<!--#include file="header.inc"-->
...
```

more [here](http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/password_protect.asp)

Comment: Not necessarily, there is a session object in ASP... http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_sessions.asp

Comment: `Session` object is to keep variables across the user session, and you still have the `Application` variable that is across the website ... ohh wait, was this what he was asking?

Comment: I think you may have not only the wrong end of the stick, but the wrong stick :-)

Comment: only now I saw the `sql` tag, ehehehe - my Bad!

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you mean a database connection? If so, *No* you should never store any ADO objects in a session variable; it wont scale & because they are apartment threaded they cannot use a thread pool.

You should connect and disconnect on each page as & when needed (i.e usually only once).
The behind the scenes [Connection Pooling](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191572) means this has less of an impact than you might assume.